# JavaScript Regular Expression: Non-Digit Character

Tags: javascript, regex

How do I say remove a number preceded by a non-digit and followed by a dash, but leave the preceding non-digit character?

```
RegExp: /[^\D]4\-/
String: http://localhost/images/4-6-.png
Remove: 4-
```

The `4-` should be removed and it should leave the preceding `/` or `-`

This would work: `/4\-/`
But it would also remove `14-` or `44-`

### Dynamic Code:

http://jsfiddle.net/flackend/8s9X9/2/

### Static Code:

```
var category_id = 4;
var src         = 'http://localhost/images/4-6-.png';
var regexp      = new RegExp('[^\\D]'+ category_id +'\\-')

$('p').append('regexp: '+ regexp +'<br>');
$('p').append(src +'<br>');

src = src.replace(regexp, '');

$('p').append(src);
```

Comment: This is a pretty good place to test regexs http://www.gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: Do you mean `/\D4-/`? `[^\D]` is equivalent to `\d`.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

You want `[\D]` or `[^\d]`, but not `[^\D]`. Regex is case-sensitive, `\d` matches a digit, and `\D` matches anything but a digit.